# ReactJS rendering multiple UI components via map iteration

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I looked around and haven't really found a solution for this yet. I want to render multiple UI elements via the `.map()` function in React from retrieved data set through network request. I got as far as being able to populate the data value in a simple string but I can't seem to do it by calling the UI from a separate function. Here is what I have:

```
readMode: function(item) {
    return (
            <div>
                <div className="itemNo">item.itemNo</div>
                <div className="itemRef">item.itemRef</div>
                <div className="itemColor">item.itemColor</div>                     
            </div>
    )
},

render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.inventory.map(function(item){
                return this.readMode(item);
            })}
        </div>
    )       
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Inventory />, 
   document.getElementById("container")
);
```

I think I'm getting really close, bypassing all the errors but I'm left with this one at the end: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'readMode' of undefined at eval`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a plain JavaScript function in your `map` arguments, you are creating a new context for that function. Because of this, the `this` value does not refer to your class but to that function's context. Two solutions are:

1) bind `this` to the existing `map` function: `(function(item){ //logic}).bind(this)`

2) the better alternative assuming you can use ES6, use arrow functions. Arrow functions inherit context from the parent so you automatically solve the issue:

```
this.state.inventory.map(item => this.readMode(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

Addition to @ZekeDroid's answer, you can write it in more simpler way like this:

```
readMode: function() {
    return this.state.inventory.map((item, i)=>{
        return (
            <div key={i}>
                <div className="itemNo">{item.itemNo}</div>
                <div className="itemRef">{item.itemRef}</div>
                <div className="itemColor">{item.itemColor}</div>                     
            </div>
        )
    })

},

render: function() {
    return (
        <div>            
            {this.readMode()}           
        </div>
    )       
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Inventory />, 
   document.getElementById("container")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't think that you need to bind anything. You can just declare your function outside the component, because you don't need 'this':

```
const readMore = (item) => { return <div>{item.name}</div>; }
```

then you can just use:

```
this.state.inventory.map(() => {return readMore(item); });
```